# What to do with question that are not narrowed to specific problem

Tags: discussion, questions

In other words, what to do with question like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530238/creating-a-group-chat-using-java-servlet

The question contains a trivial specific problem but title and description hide it too well - title is too general and unrelated to the problem.

Editing the question to narrow down the problem would mean a complete rewrite which confilcts with a rule that editing should respect the original author. (or not?)

What are the other options?

Comment: Well, aside from that post not looking like salvaging it would be worthwhile, downvoting and closing are both appropriate actions...